# How to reset user password for a MediaWiki instance using sqlite database?

Tags: mediawiki, passwords, password-recovery

The web server does not have email functionality, so the regular "forget password" feature does not work from the password resetting web page.

Also the [standard documentation on resetting password](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords) does not explain how to do it for sqlite database.

How does one translate

> MySQL salted (make sure both instances of "somesalt" are the same)
>
> ```
> UPDATE `user` SET user_password = CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-', MD5('somepass')))) WHERE user_name = 'someuser';
> ```
>
> PostgreSQL unsalted

to suitable sqlite command?

Answer (score 0):

The docs *do* tell, when they say to [use the command-line](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords#Use_the_changePassword.php_maintenance_script).

```
php maintenance/changePassword.php --user=example --password=newpassword
```

Do you also lack shell access?